# redis keep reconnecting when it was been closed？

Tags: ioredis

I closed the redis to check the err-handle, but it keep reconnecting

```
const redis = new Redis(
  Object.assign({}, config.redis.server, {
    retryStrategy(times) {
      return Math.min(times * 100, 3000);
    }
  })
)

redis.on('error', err => {
  console.log(`redis error:${err.toString()}`);
});
```

err message log:

```
redis error:Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
```

Answer (score -1):

This problem solved by the code:

```
const redis = new Redis(
  Object.assign({}, config.redis.server, {
    retryStrategy(times) {
      if (times > 10) {  // reconnect over 10 times closed
        return false;
      }
      return Math.min(times * 100, 3000);
    }
  })
)
```

Comment: This code example is missing an explanation. It is unclear why this solution works. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.